# Component-wise addition of matrices as list elements

Tags: r

So I have a 1131 element list, with each element being a 5 by 5 matrix. The first element looks much like the other ones

```
sotest.corr.try[1]
[[1]]
            [,1]        [,2]       [,3]
[1,]  1.00000000 -0.04125426  0.1565728
[2,] -0.04125426  1.00000000  0.1199373
[3,]  0.15657281  0.11993733  1.0000000
[4,]  0.10209354  0.06125212  0.1937589
[5,] -0.19069820  0.17598585 -0.1235949
            [,4]        [,5]
[1,]  0.10209354 -0.19069820
[2,]  0.06125212  0.17598585
[3,]  0.19375885 -0.12359492
[4,]  1.00000000 -0.08771679
[5,] -0.08771679  1.00000000
```

Starting at element 126, I'd like to just add the preceding 125 matrices to 126. So that the component in the 1,2 spot, for example, would be the sum of the first 126 1,2 components. I've noticed that something like this gets what I want

```
sotest.corr.try[[1]]+sotest.corr.try[[2]]
            [,1]        [,2]       [,3]       [,4]
[1,]  2.00000000 -0.08842164  0.3155670  0.2063603
[2,] -0.08842164  2.00000000  0.2363135  0.1156103
[3,]  0.31556697  0.23631345  2.0000000  0.3869373
[4,]  0.20636030  0.11561033  0.3869373  2.0000000
[5,] -0.38288102  0.35103362 -0.2489587 -0.1804376
           [,5]
[1,] -0.3828810
[2,]  0.3510336
[3,] -0.2489587
[4,] -0.1804376
[5,]  2.0000000
```

But this doesn't

```
sum(sotest.corr.try[[1:126]])
Error in sotest.corr.try[[1:126]] : recursive indexing failed at level 2
```

Is there any way to do this quickly? Maybe using lapply?
Thanks

Comment: `[[` is used for extracting a single list element.  For multiple use `[`.  If you need the sum of all `unlist` and get the `sum` i..e `sum(unlist(sotest.corr.try))` Or if it is elementwise, use `Reduce("+", sotest.corr.try[1:126])`

Answer (score 3):

For purposes of illustration suppose we have a list L of 5 2x2 matrices and we want the output to be the first two, followed by the cumulative sums for the others.

**1)** We concatenate the first two components of the list with everything but the first two components of the cumulative sum list computed using `Reduce`.

```
# test input
M <- matrix(1:4, 2)
L <- list(M, 2*M, 3*M, 4*M, 5*M)

ix <- 1:2
out1 <- c(L[ix], Reduce(`+`, L, acc = TRUE)[-ix])

# check
out2 <- list(L[[1]], L[[2]], L[[1]] + L[[2]] + L[[3]], 
L[[1]] + L[[2]] + L[[3]] + L[[4]], L[[1]] + L[[2]] + L[[3]] + L[[4]] + L[[5]])
identical(out1, out2)
## [1] TRUE
```

**2)** A simple for loop would also work.  Input `L` is from (1).

```
L2 <- L
for(i in seq_along(L2)[-1]) L2[[i]] <- L2[[i]] + L2[[i-1]]
ix <- 1:2
out3 <- c(L[ix], L2[-ix])

# check - out2 is from (1)
identical(out2, out3)
## [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are two other options using `apply` or `rowSums` with `array` (borrow data from  [G. Grothendieck's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70559191/12158757))

```
> apply(
+   array(
+     do.call(
+       cbind,
+       L
+     ), c(2, 2, length(L))
+   ), 1:2, sum
+ )
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   15   45
[2,]   30   60

> rowSums(
+   array(
+     do.call(
+       cbind,
+       L
+     ), c(2, 2, length(L))
+   ),
+   dims = 2
+ )
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   15   45
[2,]   30   60
```